# Can't ssh into ssh servers ubuntu 18.04.2LTS

Tags: server, 18.04, permissions, ssh

Got this when I tried to `ssh` into blank raspian stretch

```
@WORKSTATION:~$ ssh pi@192.168.8.107
The authenticity of host '192.168.8.107 (192.168.8.107)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:v1n3Q99Neq6ABXfdic8o8He7HqoqS+hjzpKSqYQkmJM.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? y
Please type 'yes' or 'no': yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.8.107' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
pi@192.168.8.107: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Also had that problem when I tried to `ssh` into my Ubuntu server the other day to set it up for encrypted key login. `ssh conf` file was good to go for default password login but got that same `Permission denied (publickey,password).` text. I tried it with disabled firewall and reinstalled ssh server but still same problem. 
Is something wrong with my client machine?

Comment: Your private key needs specific permissions.

Answer (score 1):

At first I can see, you've logged in the first time. The question about the fingerprint is a onetime question. Did you retried? Maybe the password was wrong. Take special care about z and y as well as special characters.

If you are using the pubkey authentication, make sure the files got the right permission.

```
pi@192.168.8.107:~$ chmod 700 .ssh/
pi@192.168.8.107:~$ chmod 640 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Than take a look at the sshd_config, what is allowed:

```
pi@192.168.8.107:~$ grep "^[^#;]" /etc/ssh/sshd_config

[...] 
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
[...]
```

And take a look what the authentication failing on the server

```
pi@192.168.8.107:~$ sudo grep sshd /var/log/auth.log
```

or in real time at login:

```
pi@192.168.8.107:~$ sudo tail -f /var/log/auth.log |grep sshd
```

An assumption, without any evidence: Does the user need to be in the group ssh? .. I really have to check if this is necessary.

Comment: I don't even get a chance to enter password